# How to deploy Qt C++ app to Android with PSql support

Tags: android, c++, postgresql, qt, sqlite

I have an application written in C++, using Qt5.7.  The application uses a database, and the selected technology is Postgres.

Now, Postgres avails itself on a network socket, and my pc application connects to it via localhost.  The eventual idea would be to host the database on a minimal Ubuntu server machine, like an LxC container, and simply change the connection string of the application from localhost, to whatever the IP of the new server will be.

The end goal of the project would be to deploy the application to any platform, my next step is Android.  I am experiencing the issue though that Android only has a SQLite driver available.  It shouldn't matter since the database will be remote, so the Android device doesn't require a  local Postgres database, but it still needs the qpsql driver to communicate with the remote database.

Can anybody point me in a direction that would help me to make the Android deployment ship with its own QPsql driver?  .so file that deploys with the application?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, and testing, I found an answer.  Short version: it can't be done without installing a postgres client service on the target android device.

The whole reason why android supports sqlite only, is because it is a file based database, not requiring a service that is hosted on a socket to access the database.

So, not having access to a psql-client package on android has led me to go with a json-REST solution called DreamFactory, and that's the end of that problem.